# How can I apply a recusive function here with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to fill the middle area with recursion. What is the best way to do this? I want a solution with recursion not other. How can I do that the left right top and bottom are checked?

```
'use strict'   
let bitmap = [
  '.....******.....', //.....******.....
  '....*......*....', //....*++++++*....
  '...*........*...', //...*++++++++*....
  '....*......*....', //....*++++++*....
  '.....******.....', //.....******.....
];

bitmap = bitmap.map((row) => [...row]);

const showOnPosition = (x, y) => bitmap[y][x];
//console.log(showOnPosition(4, 1));
const changeSymbol = (x, y) => (bitmap[y][x] = '+');
//console.log(changeSymbol(6, 1));

const fill = (x, y) => {
  // painted?
  if (showOnPosition(x, y) === '*') {
    return bitmap.map((row) => row.join('')).join('\n');
  } else {
    // paint!
    changeSymbol(x, y);

    return bitmap.map((row) => row.join('')).join('\n');
  }
};

console.log(fill(6, 1));
```

I want to check the surrounding elements and if they are not a . they should be replaced by a +. Similar to a floodFill or here only by recursion.
This is how it should look like:

```
.....******.....
....*++++++*....
...*++++++++*....
....*++++++*....
.....******.....
```

Comment: We're definitely going to need a little more explanation of the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fill recursively, you'll have to iterate over the array of one-cell differences - that is, over

```
[[0, 1], [0, -1], [1, 0], [-1, 0]]
```

From those, identify the new X and Y, and call `fill` again if that coordinate hasn't been filled before. Create a Set containing filled coordinates and pass it along.

Since `[6]` doesn't exist on the outer array, it sounds like you also need to switch around the X and Y coordinates in the parameters. (`fill(6, 1)` should refer to `bitmap[1][6]`)

```js
'use strict'   
const bitmap = [
  '.....******.....', //.....******.....
  '....*......*....', //....*++++++*....
  '...*........*...', //...*++++++++*....
  '....*......*....', //....*++++++*....
  '.....******.....', //.....******.....
]
  .map(row => [...row]);

const fill = (y, x, filled = new Set()) => {
  if (bitmap[x][y] === '.') {
    // paint!
    bitmap[x][y] = '+';
    // recurse
    for (const [xDiff, yDiff] of [[0, 1], [0, -1], [1, 0], [-1, 0]]) {
      const newX = x + xDiff;
      const newY = y + yDiff;
      const key = `${newX}_${newY}`;
      if (!filled.has(key) && bitmap[newX]) {
        filled.add(key);
        fill(newY, newX, filled);
      }
    }
  }
  return bitmap.map((row) => row.join('')).join('\n');
};

console.log(fill(6, 1));
```

Comment: Thank you, I have solved it differently. But the tip `[[0, 1], [0, -1], [1, 0], [-1, 0]]` was great and helped me a lot.